# Facebook Graph API. Whats the object_id of my Domain?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have the open graph tags with my app id on my website:

```
<meta name="fb_app_id" content="82034300336">
```

I have a permanent access token for read_insights.

With the following query [from here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/domain/) I got the domain_id of my domain:

```
SELECT domain_id FROM domain WHERE domain_name='www.flimmit.com'
```

But when I try something like the following query:

```
SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=362406043160 AND metric='domain_like_adds' AND end_time=end_time_date('2011-01-01') AND period=period('day')
```

I get the following error:

> Only administrators of applications,
> pages, and domains can retrieve
> Insights. The session user
> (1547365349) does not own the object
> 362406043160.

Needless to say that I am admin.

So i think that the domain_id does not equal the object_in the graph api to query stats from
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/ ?

(Domain content metrics at the bottom)

I cannot find anything on that!

What I want to achieve in the end is a picture of how many likes all the pages on my domain have...

Comment: no not really. facebook soon after offered detailed statistics online uneder facebook.com/insights, that offered just what i wanted to do and more.

Answer (score 0):

> So i think that the domain_id does not equal the object_in the graph api to query stats from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/ ?

First things first-object_id and domain_id are completely different integers.

Now- to get an object ID of a domain, what you want to do is run the query in the `object_url` table instead of `domain` table, If this does not work, I'd go with trying and granting your app permissions-`read_insights` or whatever equivalent you are interested in.

Comment: I tried that. i queried the table for 'http://www.flimmit.com'. the id i got was 113518965141. but when i try to fetch stats for that i get nothing. only an xml header and no content. I also would think that this returns me the object id of the PAGE not the domain, so i can view likes for that specific page but i want my whole domain...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like it's not FQL because basically I have seen that kind of query work.

You should consider looking carefully at how the query is being submitted.

Sorry if it sounds like a product plug, but my product offers a Free Trial. You could try to submit your query using that to see if it gets you the data. If it works from my product, then you'll have a better idea that it was the transport not the FQL itself.

Comment: well now they have domain stats in insights they are quite nice and i get the information i want!